# How to make a dynamic deeply nested routes with React Router 6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm stuck with dynamic nested routes. Please help to solve this problem.

I'm making a pet-project  e-commerce store with showcase and admin panel where admin can add/edit/remove products, categories, brands. Everyting related to admin panel should start with a route `domain.com/admin/` and all other routes (without /admin/) should be related to showcase.

My layout for showcase is:

- Menu with category list in Header component
- Category product list --> Product

My routes:

```
  const routes = useRoutes([
    {
      path: PATHS.showcase,
      element: <ShowcasePage />,
      children: [
        {
          path: '/',
          element: <DiscountProductsPage />,
        },
        {
          path: ':url',
          children: [
            {
              index: true,
              element: <CategoryPage />,
            },
            {
              path: ':id',
              element: <ProductsPage />,
            },
          ],
        },
        { path: PATHS.wishlist, element: <WishlistPage /> },
      ],
    },
    {
      path: PATHS.admin,
      element: <AdminPage />,
      children: [
        { path: PATHS.products, element: <ProductsPage /> },
        {
          path: PATHS.settings,
          element: <SettingsPage />,
        },
      ],
    },
  ]);
```

Path object:

```
export const PATHS = {
    showcase: '/',
    settings: 'settings',
    products: 'products',
    admin: '/admin/',
    wishlist: '/wishlist'
}
```

On page load I fetch categories which is an array like this:

```
const categories = [
  {
    id: '-N8A28QULvmu36EqRZDW',
    description: '',
    name: 'Hoodies',
    url: 'hoodies',
  },
  {
    id: '-z34A29MMMvmu36EqRZXX',
    description: '',
    name: 'Jeans',
    url: 'jeans',
  },
];
```

Then based on this array I create a menu list passing category as Link state:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    {categories.map((category) => (
      <li key={category.id}>
        <Link to={category.url} state={category} onClick={closeMenu}>
          {category.name}
        </Link>
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
</nav>
```

In category page I use `state={category}` for rendering data like this.

```
const CategoryPage: React.FC = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { id, name } = location.state as Category;
  const { products } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.product);
  const categoryProducts = products.filter((product) => product.category.id === id);

  return (
    <section>
      <h1>{name}</h1>
        <ProductCardList products={categoryProducts} />
    </section>
  );
};
```

Now I want to add a one more dynamic nested route. If user clicks on a product card in category page, then he should land on this url:

```
domain.com/:categoryUrl/:productId
domain.com/jeans/-s1B99QULvmu36EqCCPP
```

I added `children :id` to CategoryPage routes and with that I get an error in CategoryPage component:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'id' of
> 'location.state' as it is null.

I understand what causes the error. I don't understand how to fix that. Might be my approach for rendering CategoryPage is wrong? And I need to fix that first and then everything will work?

To clarify what I want:

- I want a base e-commerce layout with categories menu in header and a product list.
- If user clicks on category in menu then he should land on category page with products for that category
- If user clicks on a product in category page then he should land on product page with URL like this: `domain.com/jeans/-s1B99QULvmu36EqCCPP`

  ```
  children: [
    {
      path: ':id',
      element: <ProductPage />,
    },
  ```
- I added children route above for category page route because product page is a child of a category page

Comment: Do you want `CategoryPage` and `ProductPage` to render at the same time? Or one or the other? What is "children :id"? Can you clarify?

Comment: I updated my post. Please take a look at the end of post. Hope I clarify what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: So, all separate pages?

Comment: Yes. Category page has only list of products for that category. If user clicks on a product in that list then he should land on product page which looks like a header with menu and content for that product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are rendering `CategoryPage` as a layout route but it isn't rendering an `Outlet` component for nested routes to match and render their content into. Since you describe wanting to render these routes/components all separately anyway then the `Outlet` isn't want you want.

## Solution

Refactor your route config to render `CategoryPage` on an index route so `CategoryPage` and `ProductPage` are not a parent-child route relationship, per se. `"/:url"` will render an `Outlet` component by default and `CategoryPage` will be rendered as the index route when the path is *exactly* `"/:url"`, and `ProductPage` will render when the path is `"/:url/:id"`.

```
const routes = useRoutes([
  {
    path: PATHS.showcase,
    element: <ShowcasePage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/',
        element: <DiscountProductsPage />,
      },
      {
        path: ':url',
        children: [
          {
            index: true,
            element: <CategoryPage />,
          },
          {
            path: ':id',
            element: <ProductPage />,
          },
        ],
      },
      { path: PATHS.wishlist, element: <WishlistPage /> },
    ],
  },
]);
```

Comment: @qweezz Oh, good... saves me from needing to finish creating a sandbox demo to test solution. We can/should probably clean up these comments. Cheers.

Comment: I'm very sorry(( excuse me

Comment: @qweezz Yes, something further?

Comment: May I ask one more question? On showcase page with route '/' I render DiscountProductsPage which is basically looks like CategoryPage. It contains a list of discounted products. Now if I click on a product in this list I land on domain.com/:id but I need to land on domain.com/:url/:id . Currently this page is used only on '/' but I'll add a dedicated route for it in future

Comment: @qweezz It's a bit unclear what you are asking for, but it sounds like from the `DiscountProductsPage` you want to compute link targets that include a product's category (*url*) and id values.

Comment: I think you understood correctly what I want. On route '/' I render DiscountProductsPage - its basically has the same layout as CategoryPage — a list of discounted product cards. If I click on any product card then I land on domain.com/:id - which doesn't exists so blank page is rendered ....but actually I'd like to land domain.com/:url/:id like in a ProductsCategory pages

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247185/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-qweezz).